# show progress indicator when moving between applications

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm using IdentityServer4 for authentication/Authorization, which is a standalone application

In the client application (ASP.NET MVC), if a user clicks login, they are redirected to IDS4, After a successful login, they are redirected back to the client application.

Currently, during the redirects, the page is blank, like nothing is happening. Does anyone know if there is a way to show a progress indicator/spinner when redirecting between IDS4 and the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is not possible, largely for security reasons. When you're navigating from one domain to the other, the browser needs to do a nice clean hand-off to prevent data contamination (see [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) for an outline for why this matters).

I've done something similar in the past and the best solution seems to be optimising the client application so that it immediately renders a loading screen as soon as the first resources are fetched, and then dynamically load the rest of the app behind it. This is a bit harder in ASP.NET because the initial page can't be delivered until the server-side render is done, but it is possible.